# what's difference between interface.method() and method()

Tags: c#, interface

I've got 1 solution contains 2 project - 1 console app, 1 class library.
Class library: 
**Istep.cs**

```
interface Istep
{
    bool Excute();
}
```

**Sample.cs**

```
bool Istep.Excute()
{
   // do something
}
```

**Console app - program.cs**

```
Sample sample=new Sample();
sample.           // this can't found Excute method
```

if i change Sample.cs as following:

```
Public bool Excute()
```

sample can find excute method .

```
public class Sample : Istep
```

after i changed Excute without full qualified function name, right click Istep, click implement interface, VS will genarate a new excute method with full qualified name. so that's my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read [Explicit Interface Implementation Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! changed with full qualified name also works **Program.cs**  `Sample sample = new Sample();  Istep istep=sample;  istep.Excute();`